# SolrNet - How to disable quotes in SolrQueryByField?

Tags: solr, quotes, solrnet

I am using SolrQueryByField to test how Solr performs when searching particular fields. However SolrQueryByField seems to apply quotes around multi-word query. The final url has something like.. select?q=(prodname:"champion+creatine") ... This try to do an exact match. Is there a way to disable quotes in SolrQueryByField so that it translates into .. select?q=(prodname:champion+creatine).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following in SolrNet:

```
var q = new SolrQuery("prodname:champion") && new SolrQuery("prodname:creatine");
var response = solr.Query(q);
```

Which will produce:

```
 select?q=prodname:champion+prodname:creatine
```

This should accomplish what you want. If not, please reference the [SolrNet - Querying](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying) page for more options. Also, I believe the reason you are seeing the behavior described in your question is because `SolrQueryByField` performs special character escaping.

Edit: Using fix for SolrQueryByField mentioned in comment. (Make sure you have a version of SolrNet that supports this…

```
 var q = new SolrQueryByField("prodname", "champion creatine") { Quoted = false };
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It looks like this was a known issue and there is a fix for it http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=157 I am just not sure how to use the option to remove quotes while using SolrQuerybyfield.

Comment: Updated with how to use SolrQueryByField without quotes.

Comment: I am using SolrNet 0.4.0.1001. It doesn't seems to support the Quotes attribute. Can you please tell me which version I should use?

Comment: You will need to pull the source from https://github.com/mausch/solrnet and compile it to get this support.